# How to use leaflet-search for a geojson feature property?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to use the **leaflet-search** plugin to search for a specific geojson property (i.e. 'Name'). The trick part of this is I want to perform a search on a Geojson file thats loaded in via the **FileLayerLoad** plugin for leaflet.

So far my code is:

```
 var map = L.map('map').setView([43.7001100, -79.4163000], 17);
    mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    mapquestLink = '<a href="http://www.mapquest.com//">MapQuest</a>';
    mapquestPic = '<img src="http://developer.mapquest.com/content/osm/mq_logo.png">';

    //Main map layer:
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; '+mapLink+'. Tiles courtesy of '+mapquestLink+mapquestPic,
        maxZoom: 18,
        subdomains: '1234',
        }).addTo(map);  


    var style = {color: "green", opacity: 1.0, fillOpacity: .5, weight: 2, clickable: true ,smoothFactor:10,noClip:true,lineCap:"round"};
    L.Control.FileLayerLoad.LABEL = '<i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>';

    //Loads external geojson file:
     var control = new L.Control.fileLayerLoad({
        fileSizeLimit: 5000,
        fitBounds: true, //MOVE THE CENTER OF THE SCREEN
        layerOptions: {style: style, 
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup( "Name: " + feature.properties.Name );
        }
        }
    }).addTo(map);

    //Search within specified layer:
    map.addControl(L.control.search({layer: control, propertyName: 'Name', circleLocation:true}));
```

The problem in the above code is in the L.control.search({layer:control... line, it calls the 'control' variable, which interprets this as a new fileLayerLoad call. I'm wondering how do I search within the layer thats already loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `search` control in the `data:loaded` callback instead.

Also, it looks like you forgot to `new` the search control itself. See [docs for leaflet-search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search)

Try this:

```
control.loader.on('data:loaded', function (e) {
  // Remove old control, if any
  if (window.searchControl)
  {
    map.removeControl(window.searchControl);
  }

  // Add search gadget for this layer      
  window.searchControl= new L.control.search({
    layer: e.layer, 
    propertyName: 'Name', 
    circleLocation:true});

  map.addControl(window.searchControl);    
});
```

Comment: Tried that, it still gives me the same problem. The problem basically is when you click on the search icon in the map window, it tries to load a file just the same as if it was the 'fileLayerLoad' icon. That's why I'm think that its interpreting it as a new fileLayerLoad call.

Comment: What if you try loading the search control in the `data:loaded` callback for the file layer control instead then? (See updated answer)

Comment: Yep, that allows me to search for the feature name when loading a file. Just another question, since the callback fires every time you load a file, it creates a new search bar every time. Is there a way to only have one search bar regardless of how many file you load ? Maybe a line like control.loader.off  or something ?

Comment: Yeah if you save a reference to the control you can remove it before re-adding it. See updated example (but I didn't test it out so consider it as sorta psuedocode)

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you, so that others can see this for future reference.. thanks